# waypoints.js get id from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I try to use waypoints.js to update the url on a one page website. The waypoints event is firing correct but i cant get the id out of the section i scrolled to. The variable is always undefined.

```
$('section').waypoint(function() {
    var hash = $(this).attr('id');

    window.location.hash = (hash);
    currentHash = hash;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. You should use the this of waypoints.js:

```
$('section').waypoint(function() {
    var hash = this.element.id

    window.location.hash = (hash);
    currentHash = hash;
});
```